# How to replace the variable from controller to into a (.php) file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have an empty test.php file,in that file, I've inserted data below shown.
This code is form controller. This trace data coming from UI using ajax.

Here my $trace array data like this :

```
array(

   [0] => $test1 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
   [1] => $test2 = "1,2,3,4,7";
   [2] => $test3 = "1,4,6,7,9,0";
)
```

This is coming from UI

```
 $trace = $this->input->post('trace');
     $viewsDir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project/application/views/html_v3/';
        $fp = fopen($this->viewsDir.'test.php', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, "<?php \n\n");
        $i = 0;
        if($trace){
           foreach ($trace as  $value) {
            fwrite($fp, $trace[$i]."\n");
            $i++;                   
             }
        }
        fwrite($fp, "\n?>");
        fclose($fp);
```

After inserted my data into test.php file then the file look like this:

```
<?php
$test1 = "1,2,3,4,5";
$test2 = "5,2,0,6,5";
$test3 = "4,8,9,7,1";
?>
```

Here, if once again I want to insert data into test.php file, my $trace array data like this:

```
aray(
[0] => $test1 = "9,9,9,9,9";
[1] => $test2 = "1,1,1,1,1";
[2] => $test4 = "1,2,6,7,8";
)
```

Here my query is how can I replace this ($trace)array variables if matched with test.php. If not matched it should be added to the test.php file.

Here my expected output is:

```
<?
$test1 = "9,9,9,9,9";
$test2 = "1,1,1,1,1";
$test3 = "4,8,9,7,1";
$test4 = "1,2,6,7,8";
 ?>
```

I tried like this,but i don't know how to compare my array($trace) and content of test.php

```
$file = $this->viewsDir.'test.php';  
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
echo $contents; //i will get content of test.php based on this i have to replace or add
```

Please help me,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure I should help you with that. There is possibly something very wrong with your design if you're passing php code via POST and save it to a source file.

Anyways...

I'd declare helper function that 'parses' entry string line as key `$trace1` and value `"1,2,3,4,5"` and adds it to array `$arr`

```
function addToTrace(&$arr, $entry) {
    $entry = trim($entry);

    if(substr($entry, 0, 1) == "$") {
        $elements = explode("=", $entry);
        if(count($elements) !== 2) {
            return false;
        }
        $elements = array_map('trim', $elements);

        $arr[$elements[0]] = $elements[1];

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

After that it's only a matter of reading the file first, adding all entries to new array `$currTrace`

```
$currTrace = [];

$fp = fopen($this->viewsDir . 'test.php', 'r');

if($fp) {
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $line = fgets($fp);

        addToTrace($currTrace, $line);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

than adding new trace from post (ovewriting matching keys):

```
if($trace){
    foreach ($trace as  $value) {
        addToTrace($currTrace, $value);
    }
}
```

and saving `$currTrace` to file:

```
$fp = fopen($this->viewsDir . 'test.php', 'w');

fwrite($fp, "<?php \n\n");
foreach($currTrace as $key => $value) {
    fwrite($fp, $key . " = " . $value . "\n");
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: HI @kaczmen ,thanks for your response ,i am sorry i did not get your code ,could please explain ,i am not understanding  addToTrace(&$arr, $entry) this function and i am new to the codeiginter .Thanks